# Tweepy のハッシュタグ検索で、期間を指定した場合に結果が取得できない

Tags: python, twitter, webapi

Tweepyを使って#MeTooMenというハッシュタグを含むツイートを取得したいです。
Twitterを確認した限り、このハッシュタグを含むツイートはたくさんあったのですがTweepyで取得できません。
どうすれば解決できるか教えていただきたいです。

```py
import os
import tweepy as tw
import pandas as pd

api_key = '*'
api_secret_key = '*'
access_token = '*'
access_token_secret = '*'

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Define the search term and the date_since date as variables
search_words = "#metoomen"
date_since = "2017-10-17"
date_until = "2018-01-31"

tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q = search_words,
              lang = "en",
              since = date_since,
              until = date_until).items(5)

users_locs = [[tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.user.location, tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]

users_locs

>>> []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

検索には7日間という制限があります。Standard Searchでは、それを超えての検索はできません。

[Standard search API | Docs | Twitter Developer Platform](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets#parameters)

> until     Returns tweets created before the given date. Date should be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week.